# Windows processes vs. applications

Tags: windows, process, wmi

I can easily identify running processes by looping through the WMI `Win32_Process` elements.  Is there a similar way to identify "applications" as in Task Manager?  I assume that this is comparable to knowing whether the process has an open window.  For example, when you exit Outlook, the `OUTLOOK.EXE` process keeps running.  Task Manager no longer shows it as an application, but the process is still there.  I want to be able to determine this difference from a script.  I think I can handle examples in most any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the way to do that is to enumerate all of the top-level windows.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183009

Comment: Is there a WMI object for that?  That would definitely answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it does what you are asking: [Running Processes/Applications](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/cb972d77-0892-4bf7-834d-c23b6dd5c03a/c--get-the-all-running.aspx)